# Blazor clear memory with IDisposable

Tags: c#, blazor, dispose, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor page which loads thousands of rows asynchronously. Within Visual Studio I see that once I load this data my Blazor app uses more than one gig in memory. No problem so far. However, the memory is not freed again when changing the page.

So I implemented `IDisposable` which cancels the async operation and set my list with data to null but this does not seem to work as expected. The `Dispose` method is called when the page is changed, but the memory consumption remains at 1 gigabyte.

Does anybody know what I did wrong?

Here is my code:

```
public List<ErloesKalkulatorServiceResult> Daten { get; set; } = new List<ErloesKalkulatorServiceResult>();

protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (!disposedValue)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            Daten = null!;
            cancellationToken?.Cancel();
        }

        // TODO: free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override finalizer
        // TODO: set large fields to null
        disposedValue = true;
    }
}

 ~ErloesKalkulator()
 {
     // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in 'Dispose(bool disposing)' method
     Dispose(disposing: false);
 }

public void Dispose()
{
    // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in 'Dispose(bool disposing)' method
    Dispose(disposing: true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}
```

Comment: The runtime is not required to release the memory it has acquired, since it will try to reuse it for new allocations

Comment: Yes but I don't want the whole application to block this memory permanently. Because all other pages are using just a few MB. So 1 gig is pretty much overkill.

Comment: Just setting the collection to `null` is not always sufficient. First of all the GC will not free resources the moment you call `Dispose`. It can happen at anytime instead. The GC has access to the list of active roots that the just-in-time (JIT) compiler and the runtime maintain. Using this list, the GC creates a graph that contains all the objects that are reachable from the roots. If there is a single instance that maintains a strong reference to your items and this single instance is reachable from the root, then the item can't be collected.

Comment: One example is when the items have subscribed to an event of a reachable instance. There are other scenarios too. You should use a memory profiler like the Visual Studio debugging tool to take and inspect a snapshot from the current heap, to find the objects that occupy the memory, after you have changed the page or called `Dispose`. The profiler also shows you the reference graph. Also verify that `Dispose` is actually called.

Comment: In your case implementing `IDisposable` is not required. If you understood the previous explanation on how the GC decides which objects to collect, you would know that you only have to remove all references to the owning type (e.g., remove the page from the view, unhook event handlers) in order to make this instance and all its referenced instances (sub-tree) eligible for garbage collection. But when there are unmanaged objects which can't be tracked (managed) by the GC, then those objects must be explicitly disposed in order to let the GC know that the instance (and its sub-tree) is eligible.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I still don't get it. I have created a very small example in a .NET Core console project. But I don't know why the List within my object is still there even after I exited my Test method. https://github.com/MarvinKlein1508/CSharp_GC_Tests

Comment: This is not a question but a misunderstanding of how Memory is managed. Your best option is to remove all that code (except the List).

Comment: You are in a class derived from a Library class. The ~destructor is useless, the SuppressFinalize() is dangerous.

Comment: I have reviewed your GitHub code. Your code does absolutely nothing special: populate a collection of 10 million items, assign it to a field  and then set this field to `null`. Nothing special. The GC will handle this or it would be terribly broken. I can only repeat what I have posted before: the GC will not collect any objects immediately when they are eligible.

Comment: The reason why managed languages like C# or Java (or the applications) are slower than unmanaged languages like C++ is the GC. When GC gets active he will walk the complete stack to track each objects references. It builds and maintains an object graph. It tracks life time to group objects into generations. There is a lot of overhead going on. It's worth the price as you get the most efficient memory management without stressing the developer. But it makes code execute "slow". To minimize the impact of the GC on the applications performance the GC is highly optimized.

Comment: One basic optimization is that the GC won't execute and interrupt the application on every `Dispose` call. Additionally it takes time before an object's heap memory actually gets freed, as every objects has to go through several stages (generations). This takes time too.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you what I did in a similar situation.  My app gets data from the database, populates a list which is used in the UI.

So in your code, put List.Clear() in the Dispose method of the page.

Then run the garbage collector. It really will reduce the heap size.

Originally, I did NOT use List.Clear(), and it did appear to me to never clear the data from memory.  The app would grow in size until IIS took over and recycled the AppPool which forced the memory to be cleared.  I am aware of the fact that such memory should be automatically cleared, but for me it was a problem as it appeared to be leaking memory.

However, you have to use the Diagnostic Tools Window within Visual Studio to see the actual heap size.  If you are looking in the task manager, you will see only the amount of memory which is currently allocated to it as a whole.  So it's not likely to reduce in size.  However, if you looked in the Diagnostic Window and did a memory dump, you could see the actual current size of the heap and I bet you it would show you that the objects were in fact released, even if the app didn't let go of the memory.

Note that you should not be calling GC by hand except in usual circumstances like yours.

In the below screenshot, I called the GC for testing purposes using GC.Collect().  The second Snapshot shows the reduced memory.  I have also reported this here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/39238

[image]